# One user, three accounts - declined

Tags: support, user-accounts

I flagged a question a while ago to point out three accounts which look to me to belong to one user. The flag was declined, no evidence. Fair enough. But how can I get that decision reviewed?

If there is a choice, I'd prefer not to post the details here, but can do if that is what is needed.

> User 1 Active for a few months, asks 72 questions up to the beginning of March, none since
>
> User 2 Asks 48 questions, early March to early April
>
> User 3 Asks 12 questions early April to now
>
> There are several possible starting points, so I'll start with the question I flagged:
>
> User 3 asks question. Some answers. Some comments, asking for line with error to be indicated. User 1 updates question and indicates lines in error. User 1 comments to say thanks for the answers, I've sorted it out now. User 1 also writes an answer to the question, but not as a "self-answer".
>
> User 1 has a particular style of doing a particular something with a particular language. I've not encountered this style, it it is likely to be very localised to the user's site.
>
> User 2 and User 3 have the same style.
>
> User 1, several months ago, answered a question from 2009. Today, User 3 answered the same question. User 1's answer was upvoted, as were five of User 1's questions, at about the same time as the answer was made (all the upvotes within a minute, I assume they will be automatically reversed).
>
> User 2's single comment on a question not their own, was on a downvoted (-5) by User 3, and saying that they thought it an interesting question.
>
> When asked whether they were User 2, User 3 replied that they were a female firstname, which name is associated (via an internet search) with User 1's far from common full name (a likely female relative).
>
> Although it is recent, there are upvotes on various of the questions/answers from this group of accounts which don't seem to be warranted by the content. Never more than two. Sometimes taking a negative question to zero or positive, sometimes on an answer.
>
> Many of the questions are favourited by two or three people, despite questions not being great.
>
> And more.

I think these three accounts are the same person. I think that the new accounts were to leave the original cleaner. Then with the arrival of User 3, a little inflation and helping-out amongst the accounts is going on.

Obviously this, and the detail behind it, does not fit in the titchy little box for flagging a question, and I've already failed by flagging anyway.

What, if anything, should I do about this now?

Got response to the email:

> We actually don't mind when people maintain multiple accounts. The
> problem with multiple accounts is that they sometimes get used for
> nefarious purposes, like vote fraud. I just reviewed these accounts,
> and I don't see anything actionable.

Case closed. Moving on.

OK. It took me several attempts to get to those last two sentences, but I got there...

Comment: One option would be E-Mailing `team@stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @Pëkka Thanks. That sounds good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pekka's suggestion of contacting is definitely the way to go. Either through email (team@stackoverflow.com) or by using the contact us feature link at the bottom of every page.

Posting full detail here on meta would be inappropriate since this is a lot of observation and it would be calling a particular user or user(s) out who may not be at fault. The dev team has ways of investigating this that a normal diamond mod does not have access to.

Comment: Contacting via a mail is non-game feature - the site was not design to investigate utilizing a human factor. One just need to play by rules but not cheat via email.

Comment: @Xsi - How is that "cheating"?

Comment: Wait what. It was all a game? I've been lied to :(